# How to cut some text?

Tags: text, latex, cut

I have long section titles in my document like:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Proin nibh augue, suscipit a, scelerisque sed, lacinia in, mi.
```

Now I want to place it in page header but it is to long for it. Is there any way to cut text in LaTeX? I want to have it like that:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur...
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6862/how-can-i-display-a-short-chapter-name-in-the-header-and-a-long-chapter-name-in-t